# Why my program to scrape NSE website gets blocked in servers but works in local?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This python code is running on the local computer but is not running on

1. Digital Ocean
2. Amazon AWS
3. Google Collab
4. Heroku

and many other VPS. It shows different errors at different times.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'beta.nseindia.com',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'dnt': '1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8',
}

params = (
    ('symbol', 'BANKNIFTY'),
)

response = requests.get('https://nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative', headers=headers, params=params)

#NB. Original query string below. It seems impossible to parse and
#reproduce query strings 100% accurately so the one below is given
#in case the reproduced version is not "correct".
# response = requests.get('https://nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=BANKNIFTY', headers=headers)
```

Is there any mistake in the above code? What I am missing? I copied the header data from Chrome Developer Tools> Network in incognito mode used https://curl.trillworks.com/ site to generate the python code from the curl command.

But the curl command is working fine and giving fine output-

```
curl "https://nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=BANKNIFTY" -H "authority: beta.nseindia.com" -H "cache-control: max-age=0" -H "dnt: 1" -H "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1" -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36" -H "sec-fetch-user: ?1" -H "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" -H "sec-fetch-site: none" -H "sec-fetch-mode: navigate" -H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8"  --compressed
```

How come the curl command is working but the python generated out of the curl command is not?

Comment: Many API providers will block requests from cloud vendors - they do not want to be scraped. Most likely they will also employ some sort of rate-limiting.

Comment: Anyway to bypass it?

Comment: Not that I know of. Scraping (and bypassing a scrape-block) might also be a legal and/or ethical problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the nsefetch() function as documented here https://unofficed.com/nse-python/documentation/nsefetch/

In case you want `python-requests` method

```
from nsepython import *
payload= nsefetch('https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=BANKNIFTY')
print(payload)
```

This will work in all desktops and laptops.

In case you want `curl` method

```
from nsepythonserver import *
payload= nsefetch('https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=BANKNIFTY')
print(payload)
```

This will work in all servers. Like Linux servers.

Comment: Returns Resource not found in maxpain.txt.

Comment: This actually worked for me. However this shows that nse has not blacklisted AWS cloud IP but its HTTP2 which is not letting users receive response. I am trying hyper (python) but taking a shortcut using the above mentioned approach to solve the problem first and later will resume to hyper.

Comment: Just works for this URL, other urls such as 'https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/niftyStockWatch.json' don't return or return 'Resource not found'

Comment: It did work for me on my EC2 machine

Comment: however, it does throw `Resource not found` at times

Comment: It is not working now.

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 things that are to be noted.

1. Request header needs to have 'host' and 'user-agent'

```
__request_headers = {
        'Host':'www.nseindia.com', 
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0',
        'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 
        'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5', 
        'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
        'DNT':'1', 
        'Connection':'keep-alive', 
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
        'Pragma':'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control':'no-cache',    
    }
```

2. Following cookies are dynamically set, which needs to be fetched and set dynamically.

```
'nsit',
'nseappid',
'ak_bmsc'
```

These are set from nse based on the functionality that is being used.
This example: top gainers / losers.
I tried to get top gainers and losers list, in which the request is blocked without these cookies.

```
try:
            nse_url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/top-gainers-loosers'
            url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-variations?index=gainers'
            resp = requests.get(url=nse_url, headers=__request_headers)
            if resp.ok:
                req_cookies = dict(nsit=resp.cookies['nsit'], nseappid=resp.cookies['nseappid'], ak_bmsc=resp.cookies['ak_bmsc'])
                tresp = requests.get(url=url, headers=__request_headers, cookies=req_cookies)
                result = tresp.json()
                res_data = result["NIFTY"]["data"] if "NIFTY" in result and "data" in result["NIFTY"] else []
                if res_data != None and len(res_data) > 0:
                    __top_list = res_data
        except OSError as err:
            logger.error('Unable to fetch data')
```

Another thing to be noted is that these requests are blocked by NSE from most of the cloud VMs like AWS, GCP. I was able to get it from personal windows machine, but not from AWS or GCP.

Comment: Always getting connection timeout on server, working fine on local system.