# python requests lib is not working in amazon aws

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, python-requests

I am trying following code:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.nseindia.com',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36 OPR/72.0.3815.320',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
}

nse = requests.Session()
x = nse.get("https://www.nseindia.com/", headers=headers)

print(x.text)
```

Following code is working on my pc but when I put it in aws it is not responding.

I have also checked ping `https://www.nseindia.com/` it is working.

requests is working for other sites like google but not working for this specific site on aws.

In EC2:

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> headers = {
...     'authority': 'www.nseindia.com',
...     'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
...     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36 OPR/72.0.3815.320',
...     'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
...     'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
...     'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
...     'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
...     'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
...     'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
... }
>>> nse = requests.Session()
>>> nse.get("https://www.nseindia.com/", headers=headers)
```

No output from last line.

In my PC:

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> headers = {
...     'authority': 'www.nseindia.com',
...     'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
...     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36 OPR/72.0.3815.320',
...     'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
...     'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
...     'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
...     'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
...     'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
...     'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
... }
>>> nse = requests.Session()
>>> nse.get("https://www.nseindia.com/", headers=headers)
<Response [200]>
>>>
```

Problem detected:

IN EC2

```
ping www.nseindia.com
PING www.nseindia.com (23.9.215.115) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from a23-9-215-115.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.9.215.115): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=1.07 ms
64 bytes from a23-9-215-115.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.9.215.115): icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=1.09 ms
```

IN PC

```
ping www.nseindia.com
PING www.nseindia.com (23.35.32.140) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from a23-35-32-140.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.35.32.140): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=65.8 ms
64 bytes from a23-35-32-140.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.35.32.140): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=61.5 ms
64 bytes from a23-35-32-140.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.35.32.140): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=73.1 ms
```

ping to different IP.

Comment: What do you mean with "is not responding"? To who,it is not responding? Do you see any exception? Does it just hang there? What do you mean "in aws", is this on an EC2 instance?

Comment: By not responding means no output after this line `x = nse.get("https://www.nseindia.com/", headers=headers)` request.get has a time_out value if you not set any value it waits till it receives any data. In this case it is not receiving any data from that site so it keeps on waiting.

Comment: yes I mean EC2 aws.

Comment: You are storing response in `x` on `EC2`.  You are not doing same on your `PC`.

Comment: @MrugeshKadia No that is not the problem :)

Comment: Having same issue for `myntra.com`.

Comment: @MrugeshKadia yes same issue for `myntra.com` I have just checked it.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this website has defences in place to try and discourage/prevent what you are trying to do. It's impossible to know what they are exactly but looks like a blanket blacklist for AWS at least.

Comment: Hi. The question bounty period finished and is in grace period. Have you considered accepting any of the answers provided?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get different IP after ping because `www.nseindia.com` is delivered to you through [akamai](https://www.akamai.com/) CDN. So you are pinging **different edge location** whether you are doing this from home/work or AWS servers.

What's more, [IP address ranges of AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) are **publicly known**. Thus, its not uncommon for websites to explicitly block AWS connections, to protect from scraping, attacks or otherwise unwanted access. Thus it seems that **nseindia is blocking** all these AWS IP addresses. It is a known issue as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740840/why-my-program-to-scrap-nse-website-gets-blocked-in-servers-but-works-in-local) and [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/12471/) for examples.

The solution is not to use AWS nor other popular could providers (nseindia also blocks others). You could try to **proxy your AWS requests** through some commercial VPN maybe, home/work network, or something that is not blacklisted. Sadly, this is try-and-see approach. But you have to also consider potential legal/ethical issues of bypassing these restrictions.

Comment: OP, you could also try a tor proxy :) https://github.com/qrtt1/aws-lambda-tor

Answer (score 0):

What is the location of the server? It is possible that nseindia is not allowing ip addresses that are outside India.
Try using any VPN or use your browser cookies to fake your location(not ethical).
Also, Session() has been depreceated. You can use sessions.Session()