# Flask application hanging indefinitely

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask

I have a very simple flask app which works fine in my Windows 10 computer localhost . But it hangs when I run it on the Ubuntu server hosted on digitalocean cloud.

```
from flask import Flask
from nsetools import Nse
   
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    nse = Nse()
    qt = nse.get_quote('TANLA')
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=4455)
```

If I remove the line 'qt = nse.get_quote('TANLA')' application works on the server also.
I had installed nsetools in virtual environment successfully using pip install nsetools.

Since app is working fine on the localhost, issue must be with the server. app runs fine on the server when it doesn't have to call nse.get_quote(). So ultimate issue has to be with this library nsetools.

I am clueless about the solution.
any help?

thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you also run Ubuntu on localhost?

Comment: no. its windows 10.

Comment: I think it's a digitalocean issue cuz it works fine on my ubuntu server.

Comment: Does the webpage not load or is it very slow?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740840/why-my-program-to-scrape-nse-website-gets-blocked-in-servers-but-works-in-local

Comment: @AribMuhtasim webpage doesn't load at all.. progress circle keep rotating..

Comment: @KawaiKx, It is definitely a DigitalOcean problem. Many APIs block requests from cloud vendors cuz they don't want their data to be scraped. You can look into a Raspberry Pi and set up your own server at home with port forwarding. There are many tutorials online. You can follow them and set up a server and have full control over it.